# Unable to navigate to the Next page in Multi page form in vue.js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js

I was unable to navigate to the Next page in Multi page form in vue.js.

```
      name: 'xxx',
      data: ()=>{
         return{     
            currentPage: -1,
            text: "Hello"
         }
      },
  }
```

binding CurrentPage inside vue template like below:

```
<div class="container" v-for="(pages, pageid) in pages_json" :currentPage="currentPage"  v-if="currentPage== pageid">
```

Based on **currentPage** value, the form will be displayed accordingly. Value starts from -1.
CurrentPage needs to be updated every time while clicking **NEXT Button** in vue.js template.

```
this.$root.$validator.validate(scope + '.*').then(valid => {
  if (valid){
    if(text == "Hello"){
      this.currentPage += 1;
    }
    else{     
      // throwing error here, since assigning value to this.currentPage
      this.currentPage = 1;  

      console.log(this.currentPage)  // updating perfectly here                
    }
});
```

Above code is used inside the method which would be called on **NEXT Button** click.
Assigning value to the vue data inside [else block] throws an error.

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` sounds like a completely different error than what you have shown here.

Comment: `if (this.text == 'Hello')` perhaps? Also, what's the point of the `:currentPage="currentPage"` attribute?

Comment: I would guess this error happens in a loop since `'0' of undefined` mostly happens in it. Maybe `v-for="(pages, pageid) in pages_json"` is causing it. Where did you initialize `pages_json` ?

Comment: ```:currentPage = "currentPage"```attribute  is just for referencing the page number ( like pagination) . Eg: If the currentPage  is assigned to 2, the page would be navigate to second page. If it is 3, then navigation will happen to third page.